# How to represent a job-sequencing?, with binary code

Tags: combinations, binary, combinatorial-game-theory

Suposse a job sequence of 6 jobs, as 3-5-4-2-6-1, that point the job 3 is attended in 1st place, and then the job 5,....

How could I represent this sequencies with binary code to use in metaheuristic Genetic Algorithms?

-- edited after ciuak solution --

The representation must have similar binary code to similar representations.

So 612345, must be similar to 612354.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Can each job appear only once? 2. Is the number of jobs given in advance?

Comment: @barakmanos, yes to all. Each job can only appear once. The number os jobs is given in advance. It´s to use binary cromosomas to represent each sequence and cand make modifications, permuttions, combine 2 sequesces to have a child,...

Comment: So given $N$ jobs, why don't you just use $\lceil\log_2N\rceil$ bits for each job? Do you need to optimize for space?

Comment: For example (answering your question): `011|101|100|010|110|001` (the `|` are just in order to make it easier to read).

Comment: $\lfloor\log_2N\rfloor+1$ bits, to be more accurate...

Comment: Be aware, that in genetic algorithms it's not enough to have just some representation. One desirable feature is that similar representations (from the perspective of crossing algorithms) encode similar objects (in the context of your problems). Another useful feature is that there is a simple meaningful crossing algorithm, e.g. merging bytes wouldn't produce incorrect representation. In particularly adding info about your merging algorithm and notion of closeness (e.g. what is closer to identity, 623451 or 214365 and why) would make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: @dtldarek Yes, it´s that the issue that make that a simple binary representation is not suitable.

Comment: I´m viewing Yamada and Nakano papers, but.. still .. I didn´t found and appropiate representation.

Comment: If you want similar codes for similar representations and non-similar codes for non-similar representations, then the only way to do it is with the standard binary-based system.

Comment: @barakmanos What´s that code?, the ordinary binary system? in that case 612345 is too difenrent from 162345. I have no solution :-) Thank you.

Comment: It's different in $6$ out of $15$ bits. Define your criterion for "too different" please.

Answer (score 1):

Easy. There are $6!$ combinations, so each number will represent a sequence.
The number will be in the form of
$$
5*4*3*2*a + 4*3*2*b + 3*2*c + 2*d + e
$$
in binary.
And understanding the "jobs code" (in this example a=2,b=1,c=2,d=0,e=1):

- We start with no numbers in our final sequence and we can pick from ${1,2,3,4,5,6}$.
- a=2, so we pick the third element (first = 0). Our numbers to pick are now ${1,2,4,5,6}$ and our combination of jobs ${3}$ for now.
- b=1, so we pick the second element. Our numbers to pick are now ${1,4,5,6}$ and our jobs combination is now ${3,2}$.
- c=2, pick: {1,4,6} and jobs: {3,2,5}.
- d=0, pick: {4,6} and jobs: {3,2,5,1}.
- e=1, pick: {4} and jobs: {3,2,5,1,6}.
- We are left with pick: {4} so we add that into the sequence: {3,2,5,1,6,4}.

This is the most efficient way (10 bits).
Our example numbers are 2,1,2,0,1 so the number we want to calculate is:
$$
120*a + 24*b + 6*c + 2*d + e = 240 + 24 + 12 + 0 + 1 = 277 = 100010101_2
$$
So your "jobs code" for 3,2,5,1,6,4 is $100010101$ in binary!

Comment: you can do the same with 24 bits while each combination of 4 bits corresponds to the job number

Comment: Your method is also known as *Factorial Number System* (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system), where the $N$th digit is represented in base $N$.

Comment: @barakmanos I didn't know it, but I'm a programmer and coding algorithms are very easy to invent for me :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in order to make it work properly, you should subtract $1$ from each job-number before encoding (e.g., use 2-4-3-1-5-0 instead of 3-5-4-2-6-1), and add $1$ after decoding.

Comment: @ciuak Yes, but The code I want is that have similar represntations to similar secuences, So 612345, must be similar to 512346.

Comment: @MikaIke Then I can't help you.